# Mesh Plot Problems in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, mesh

I want to draw a `meshc` contour plot, but the contour is not being drawn as I want.

```
x = linspace(P(1),P(2)); %// x axis
y = linspace(P(3),P(4)); %// y axis
[X1 Y1] = meshgrid(x,y); %// all combinations of x, y
%[X1,Y1] = meshgrid(1:.125:3); 
Z1 = mvnpdf([X1(:) Y1(:)],mu,sigma); %// compute Gaussian pdf
Z2 = reshape(Z1,size(X1)); %// put into same size as X, Y
meshc(X1,Y1,Z2); 
%axis([1 3 1 3 -5 10]);
axis([P(1) P(2) P(3) P(4) -5 10])
```

The code above draws it this way:

[image: meshc plot 1]

But I want it to be this way:

[image]

How could I do this?

Comment: The plot shown in your "desired" image is nothing like a multivariate Gaussian - looks more like a sum of several weighted multivariate Gaussians. You cannot plot it if you compute the values using just one call to `mvnpdf`. I think your question is lacking some important details on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I changed the second picture. My problem is with the position of contour. I want it to be far from the gaussian as in the second picture

Answer (score 0):

To get desired distance between the plots you can just subtract some number from the `Z2` matrix. I cannot figure out why Matlab divides the plots in this way, but it works:

```
P = [1 3 1 3];
mu = [2 1.1];
sigma = [.09 .003; ...
         .003 .002];

x = linspace(P(1),P(2)); %// x axis
y = linspace(P(3),P(4)); %// y axis
[X1 Y1] = meshgrid(x,y); %// all combinations of x, y
Z1 = mvnpdf([X1(:) Y1(:)],mu,sigma); %// compute Gaussian pdf
Z2 = reshape(Z1,size(X1)); %// put into same size as X1, Y1

Z2 = Z2 - 0.01;

meshc(X1,Y1,Z2); 

axis([P(1) P(2) P(3) P(4) -5 10])
```

[image: Multivariate distribution and its contour plot]

Maybe you need to play with other numbers to get a desired result. In my example I subtracted a small number, in order to avoid changing of the pdf-plot range.